# How to stop developer tools window closing when restarting a chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a chrome app. Whenever I restart the app to test new code (from context menu or chrome://extensions), the developer tools window closes and I have to re-open it manually (right click > inspect element). Previous behaviour was that the developer window would also automatically re-open during this process.

Right now I'm trying to actually debug code that runs on app load, and I can't get to any break points because by the time I can manually re-launch the developer tools they've been missed.

How can I have the developer window automatically re-open when the app is restarted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You can't programmatically open the Chrome DevTools.

What I suggest is to change onload to a function, and call that from the console.

Comment: It somehow 'solved' itself and now always opens the developer tools window on open, as was the original behaviour. I don't know why it has changed, what I did to precipitate it, and I don't know how to change it back! But if you cant then moving code out of onload is the best mitigation strategy

Comment: The dev tools should reopen by themselves. However, coordinating all this stuff at window startup is pretty tricky and I think there is a race condition involved somewhere which makes them sometimes not open.